# Production issue with carrierwave and S3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I was wondering if someone could help me, I've recently added the ability to upload images in my rails application using carrierwave, fog, and S3 for storage.

The application is running on **Ruby-1.9.3-p194** and **Rails 3.2.11** and in development the application is working fine I can upload images all day long, however in production I seem to be getting an intermittent **"Excon::Errors::SocketError: Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)"** and I say intermittent because I've managed to successfully upload a couple of images in production but I get this error more often.

I've spent some time looking into it but at present I am at a loss as to what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some further digging it appears that it may have been because the region was incorrectly set in my config, I've run a test and all seems to be working correctly again.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately an incorrect region can do that. Plus it is hard to know that this is the issue from the client side (as it looks like misc network issues). Anyway, glad to hear you found the fix.